# JQuery Sometimes loads, sometimes not

Tags: jquery

My main problem:

1/ load page have autocomplete (A) - click load only, not Ctrol F5 or F5

2/ sometimes autocomplete works, sometimes does not

the error is below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lEoT.png
[This is a capture image which "luckly" i take from firebug]

Real testing on video youtube: https://youtu.be/2OsbelHapJk

how to fix them, i have stacken for 3 days... please help !
i have seen some thread like this, but no true answer...

```js
$("#txtSaveDTG").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var param2 = { Name: $('#txtSaveDTG').val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: "../../UserControls/LoadDataService.asmx/AUTOGUI",
                data: JSON.stringify(param2),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.d.length == 0) {

                        $('#txtSaveDTG').attr("placeholder", "Value is not found with '" + $('#txtSaveDTG').val() + "'");
                        $('#txtSaveDTG').val("");
                    } else {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item["Name"]
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
```

Comment: In your code, are you loading jquery.ui before the $().autocomplete code %100 of the time?

Comment: tks for reply Ammar, but why sometimes loaded, sometimes did not ? if this page used to load successfully autocomplete, why problems still be about arranging js in page ??? :)

Comment: It depends on how you have your backend setup. Some frameworks allow you to dynamically load your HTML. If you happen to load the HTML with $().autocomple() before the HTML with <script src="jquery.min.js"/> That error will happen

Comment: See: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/ and how load order matters.if tl;dr, go see the Quick Reference section.  Ideally, until HTTP2 is widespread you should bundle your scripts and have it in order in the bundle to avoid this type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

That error usually means that jQuery or the plugin hasn't yet been loaded. Sounds like there in a race, Check that you're function call isn't getting hit before the document is loaded:

```
    $(function(){
        $("#txtSaveDTG").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var param2 = { Name: $('#txtSaveDTG').val() };
            $.ajax({
                url: "../../UserControls/LoadDataService.asmx/AUTOGUI",
                data: JSON.stringify(param2),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.d.length == 0) {

                        $('#txtSaveDTG').attr("placeholder", "Value is not found with '" + $('#txtSaveDTG').val() + "'");
                        $('#txtSaveDTG').val("");
                    } else {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                value: item["Name"]
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Also check that the path to the javascript files are correct.